# Entity Framework 6 AutoDetectChangesEnabled

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

I can disable AutoDetectChangesEnabled with Entity Framework 6?

If i use `context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false`

I get the error message:

> does not contain a definition of 'Configuration' and was not found no
>   extension method 'Configuration' accepting a first argument of type

Comment: It's a property of the `DbContext` derived contexts. Are you using the older `ObjectContext`?

Comment: I'am  using this code: 

using (DBEntities db = new DBEntities())
{
      db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
}

But not work!

Comment: The question is though what `DBEntities` class is - `class DBEntities : DbContext` or `class DBEntities : ObjectContext`.

Comment: I have: public partial class DBEntities : ObjectContext. I don't' know if it is important but i'm using visual studio 2010

Answer (score 0):

I solved following this tutorial: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj206878(v=vs.113).aspx.

I had forgotten to install DbContext from NuGet